# Optimization of greater than operator

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, query-optimization

credit table and validtransaction table have million record data from year 2008 onwards.

We are doing a migration. So I need to find out the credittypeids which are no longer in use after 2017 (periodseq=1055), so that these need not be migrated.

This is the query and the >= part is resulting in huge cost. Please suggest an alternative.

```
SELECT CREDITTYPEID
FROM CREDITTYPE ct
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
  FROM CREDIT C
  WHERE C.PERIODSEQ>=1055
  AND C.CREDITTYPEID=CT.CREDITTYPEID
  );
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please post DDL for your table? Looks like you haven't got an index on that column...

Comment: Is this a one-off exercise? How much investment of time (and effort) are you prepared to spend to reduce the elapsed time of this query? For instance, it's quite possible it would take longer to build an index than you would save on executing the SELECT. Also, which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Additional the DDL of the index `CREADITYPE_PK_IND` will be helpfull. Please also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/4808122) how to post execution plan **complete** and in the **text form**.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking aggregation:

```
SELECT C.CREDITTYPEID
FROM CREDIT C
GROUP BY C.CREDITTYPEID
HAVING MAX(C.PERIODSEQ) < 1055;
```

This assumes that the credit type is used in at least one credit record.

Otherwise, for your version of the query, you specifically want an index on `CREDIT(CREDITTYPEID, PERIODSEQ)`.  The ordering of the keys matters, and this is the correct order for your query.

Comment: *"this is the correct order for your query"* Up to a point. The explain plan suggests CREDIT is partitioned on PERIODSEQ.

Answer (score 1):

This should return your (distinct!) list of `CREDITTYPEID` that were used in the past, but are not used curretnly (after PERIODSEQ 1055)

```
SELECT CREDITTYPEID  /* used before 1055 */
FROM CREDITTYPE ct
WHERE PERIODSEQ < 1055
MINUS
SELECT CREDITTYPEID /* used after 1055 */
FROM CREDITTYPE ct
WHERE PERIODSEQ>=1055;
```

As the column name suggest `CREDITTYPEID` is a *type* so there are several rows in the table with the same typeId.

The query above return only the *distinct list* and uses no hash anti join.

You may add `parallel option` (with the [PARALLEL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Comments.html#GUID-D25225CE-2DCE-4D9F-8E82-401839690A6E) hint) if your HW allows  it.

Answer (score 0):

The following index on the `CREDIT` table should help:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON CREDIT (PERIODSEQ, CREDITTYPEID);
```

This should allow the `EXISTS` clause lookup to evaluate more quickly.  You could also try the following variant index, which reverses the order of the columns:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON CREDIT (CREDITTYPEID, PERIODSEQ);
```

Comment: The `EXISTS` is most probably here the problem and it should be removed, not supported;)